# Caching JS with config.cache_classes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching, configuration, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with rails 4 Live Streaming Future (for SSE). And i have to set this in development.rb (if i set it false, page is hanging out):

```
config.cache_classes = true

config.assets.debug = true
#config.serve_static_assets = true
#config.eager_load = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false #(!!!)
```

But! Anytime when i editing js files, i had to reload server to test it in browser. It's really hard! 
Where can i disable js caching?

Would be grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. i copy config from https://github.com/milchschaum/rails_4_live_streaming

he used

```
config.assets.debug = true
# Handle multiple requests
config.preload_frameworks = true
config.allow_concurrency = true
```

full code is here https://raw.github.com/milchschaum/rails_4_live_streaming/c6318701f73bef5125cb4000bd424bdb853e893e/config/environments/development.rb

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment assets debug mode.

```
config.assets.debug = true
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it didn't help..
Here is my current development.rb config 
https://gist.github.com/Timopheym/6096257

Comment: `config.cache_classes` enable/disable caching of ruby code, you should set it to false in development mode.

Comment: Everything seems to be ok, you may try `config.assets.compile = true` but it's not recommended feature.

Comment: I added config.assets.debug = true and config.assets.compile = true but it does not helped... (

Answer (score 0):

To your *config/development.rb*, add:

```
config.allow_concurrency = true
```